# Headcount by Month Power BI

Tags: powerbi, dax

I am new to Power BI and I am looking to calculate the total employee headcount each month. I have a table with employee no, start date and leave date. The leave date is 31/12/9999 for all current employees and a date is given if an employee leaves. Also a future date can be added in the leave date column if someone is leaving in the future. I am looking to use a graph to interpret this data in Power BI.

Any advice would be appreciated.  The current measure I'm using is included below.

Thanks

```
Current Staff =
CALCULATE (
    COUNTROWS ( 'EMP_EMPLOYED_TIME_ROW' ),
    FILTER (
        VALUES ( EMP_EMPLOYED_TIME_ROW[DATE_OF_EMPLOYMENT] ),
        EMP_EMPLOYED_TIME_ROW[DATE_OF_EMPLOYMENT] <= MAX ( Dates[Date] )
    ),
    FILTER (
        VALUES ( EMP_EMPLOYED_TIME_ROW[DATE_OF_LEAVING] ),
        OR (
            EMP_EMPLOYED_TIME_ROW[DATE_OF_LEAVING] >= MIN ( Dates[Date] ),
            ISBLANK ( EMP_EMPLOYED_TIME_ROW[DATE_OF_LEAVING] )
        )
    )
)
```

Comment: current measure i have:

Current Staff = CALCULATE(COUNTROWS('EMP_EMPLOYED_TIME_ROW'),FILTER(VALUES(EMP_EMPLOYED_TIME_ROW[DATE_OF_EMPLOYMENT]),EMP_EMPLOYED_TIME_ROW[DATE_OF_EMPLOYMENT]<=MAX(Dates[Date])),filter(VALUES(EMP_EMPLOYED_TIME_ROW[DATE_OF_LEAVING]),or(EMP_EMPLOYED_TIME_ROW[DATE_OF_LEAVING]>=MIN(Dates[Date]),ISBLANK(EMP_EMPLOYED_TIME_ROW[DATE_OF_LEAVING]))))

Comment: What's wrong with this formula? Can you provide some sample input data?